# Power Bi Cumulative Formula (right formula, wrong results)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this formula (see below) to calculate the number of cumulative impressions. I have checked many times and against many sources and it seems correct, yet the results are not cumulative.

*Formula*

```
Cumulative_Impressions = CALCULATE(SUM(BE_Sprite_Limelight[M_Impressions_1]),FILTER(ALL(BE_Sprite_Limelight),BE_Sprite_Limelight[D_Date_1]<=MAX(BE_Sprite_Limelight[D_Date_1])))
```

[image: Screenshot of Results]

I have compared against multiple sources both from stackoverflow as well as other websites. I have made sure I've got all the fields right. I have a date column in the mix and it's sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separate calendar/date table in your model? You have a a date column in your fact table, but it's a whole lot more flexible to have a separate Calendar table, because you can have all kinds of custom date columns to aggregate by.

I'm just doing a running total using an existing SUM measure, and it's super easy...

```
RT Qty 2 = CALCULATE(
            [Total Qty Sold],
            FILTER(ALL('DimDate'),
                'DimDate'[Date]<=MAX('DimDate'[Date])
            )
        )
```

If I want to get a total by month/year, I can just add the Month/Year column from my date table to rows and the measure on Values and it will work.